# Function with input to define variables won't execute

Tags: python-3.x

This code works fine:

```
n1 = int(input("input a number "))
n2 = int(input("input a number "))    
print(n1 + n2)
```

However, when I try to put it in a function and execute the function like this it doesn't work:

```
def add_two(n1, n2):
    n1 = int(input("input a number "))
    n2 = int(input("input a number "))    
    return n1 + n2

add_two(n1, n2)
```

I get

Traceback (most recent call last):
File ... line 6, in 
add_two(n1, n2)
NameError: name 'n1' is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
def add_two():
    n1 = int(input("input a number "))
    n2 = int(input("input a number "))    
    return n1 + n2

add_two()
```

because `n1` and `n2` are defined in the function itself, and are not arguments that need to be passed through. When you write `add_two(n1, n2)` you are searching for any global variables called `n1` and `n1` and since they don't exist, you get an error.